# Bad value from AttributeSet.getAttributeValue()

Tags: android

I have a custom SeekBarPreference, which extends DialogPreference. I'm building my own layout, yet still using the parent's attributes.

```
<com.example.preference.SeekBarPreference
     android:key="key"
     android:title="title"
     android:summary="summary"
     android:dialogMessage="diag message"
     android:text="text"
     android:max="60"
     android:defaultValue="30" />
```

In the code section, I'm retrieving the attr.getAttributeValue(androidDns, attrKey), like so

```
mText = attrs.getAttributeValue(androidns, "text");
mMax = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(androidns, "max", 30);
...
```

The thing is that in the 'mText' member I'm getting something like "@12341234" kind of text, but 'mMax' is being set right.

How is this possible  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this helps

```
context.getString(attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(androidns, "text", 0));
```

Comment: Cleaned the project. Hard coding like above worked. However, if one chooses to use strings.xml as a source for the string, your proposed solution is the answer. 
This is also what I was looking for, so thank you!